# Log Shipping Backup grey in Transaction Log Shipping Status

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I have slow network that makes configure log shipping via GUI always timeout, so I generate script and run it in both primary server and secondary server.

The scripts work fine but the primary database not show in secondary server log shipping report if I select `[msdb].[dbo].log_shipping_monitor_primary` in secondary server my primary database not insert at that table.

1. Is there possibly something wrong when I generate or run logshipping script that makes it not configure properly?
2. How to fix this, can I manually insert at `[msdb].[dbo].log_shipping_monitor_primary` or it not enough?

Currently the backup,copy and restore works fine in my server just backup status not show at report transaction log shipping.

Comment: Can you connect with SSMS from Primary to Secondary server without problem and run queries? If connection is failing how could possibly insert work ?

Comment: I have no problem with SSMS, query even rdp from primary to secondary server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently the backup,copy and restore works fine in my server just
>   backup status not show at report transaction log shipping.

If backup, copy and restore is working fine then its objectivity is obtained and one site to another site is in sync however in case you are unable to see only the backup status, you may check this at individual job level by clicking on job history at primary server and see whether it is successful or has completed with error.

Alternatively, you may use script to check the current status of log-shipping at primary and secondary server:

```
--Primary

select * from msdb..log_shipping_monitor_primary

--Secondary

select * from msdb..log_shipping_monitor_secondary
```

Primary will give you information about backup whereas secondary will have details on both the jobs i.e. copy as well as restoration.

You may try below stored procedure also which will return result however un-formatted:

```
use master
go
exec sys.sp_help_log_shipping_monitor
go
```

> The scripts work fine but the primary database not show in secondary
>   server log shipping report if I select
>   [msdb].[dbo].log_shipping_monitor_primary in secondary server my
>   primary database not insert at that table.

This is supposed to return rows at primary server and not at secondary server, it seems you are mistake about this table.

Procedure `sp_help_log_shipping_monitor` can be run on both the nodes i.e. primary and secondary and will return result for backup on primary whereas on secondary this would give details about copy and restore.

Hope above helps.